# How to setup a new Windows 8 PC?

Tags: windows-8, desktop-computer

I just bought a new Windows 8 PC ([this one](http://www.amazon.de/Lenovo-Notebook-Pentium-Graphics-Touchscreen/dp/B00I9PW0PQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1423226124&sr=8-1&keywords=lenovo%20s210)) and I'm about to set it up.
Where should I start and is there a easy way to install or get all essential tools like WinZip, VLC etc?

Comment: Just turn it on.  You download WinZip and VLC directly from their websites.

Comment: Why should we know what exactly a PC you have bought (your link to amazon)? Does it really matters here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me say that I prefer to manually download each program at a time from the developer's site. 
However, if you prefer something more automagic, I guess that **ninite** (https://ninite.com/) is a good choice.
I haven't used it before so please check on their website what are their terms of usage. 
Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you Ninite looks great. `I prefer to manually download each program at a time from the developer's site` What is the benefit to do that instead of using Ninite?